# Why does the mouse cursor disappear when typing inside a notepad window, but not in a browser or cmd? Which Win API functions display it and how?

Tags: winapi, architecture, msdn

Why does the **mouse cursor disappear** when typing inside a `notepad.exe` or `wordpad.exe` or `run.exe` window? Which function/interrupt/etc is responsible for that? Typing in, for example, a web browser or `cmd.exe` does not result in the cursor disappearing. Which Win API functions in machine code display the mouse pointer and how (including software and hardware) and how this disappearance is low-level performed?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to Windows Sysinternals. Please explain or delete it from the title, text and tags.

Comment: See here: https://superuser.com/questions/928839/what-does-the-hide-pointer-while-typing-feature-actually-do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiding the mouser pointer while the user is typing can be voluntarily implemented by an application. Few applications do so.

Typically, you would implement it by handling Win32 API notifications:

- Hide the pointer on [WM_KEYDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown)
- Show the pointer on [WM_MOUSEMOVE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousemove) and many, many more events such a menu and window related events.

Furthermore, applications should only hide the mouse pointer if *Hide pointer while typing* is checked in the mouse pointer options (see below).

This option can be queried using the [*SystemParametersInfo()*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) WIN32 API function passing *SPI_GETMOUSEVANISH* (aka *Mouse Vanish feature*).

[image: Mouse Pointer Options]

Comment: How this operation is low-level performed including machine code and hardware?

Comment: To show or hide the mouser pointer, call [ShowCurser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showcursor). It's a function call to the dynamically linked `User32.dll`. I'm not familiar with the rest. It's likely left to the graphics card (separate or integrated), how to display the pointer.